# What to index in tables for a query using 3 INs?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have this Postgres query using 3 `IN` and 1 `NOT IN`. Can you suggest what columns should be indexed here?

```
DELETE 
FROM   myschema.sla
WHERE  pxinsname NOT IN 
       ( 
              SELECT pxinsname 
              FROM   myschema.sla
              WHERE  ( 
                            pxinsname IN 
                            ( 
                                   SELECT pxrefqueuekey 
                                   FROM   myschema.t1) ) 
              OR     ( 
                            pxinsname IN 
                            ( 
                                   SELECT pxrefqueuekey 
                                   FROM   myschema.t2) ) 
              OR     ( 
                            pxinsname IN 
                            ( 
                                   SELECT pxrefqueuekey 
                                   FROM   myschema.t3) )  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first simplify your query. Especially the subselect may be omited.

Without knowing the schema and the amount of data, it is difficult to say anything about appropriate indexes. I would try an indexes on `pxrefqueuekey` for tables `t1` to `t3`, respectively, e.g.:

```
CREATE INDEX t1_pxrefqueuekey_idx ON myschema.t1(pxrefqueuekey);
CREATE INDEX t2_pxrefqueuekey_idx ON myschema.t2(pxrefqueuekey);
CREATE INDEX t3_pxrefqueuekey_idx ON myschema.t3(pxrefqueuekey);
```

With

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM myschema.sla WHERE pxinsname NOT IN 
   ( 
          SELECT pxinsname 
          FROM   myschema.sla
          WHERE (
    pxinsname IN (SELECT pxrefqueuekey FROM myschema.t1) OR 
    pxinsname IN (SELECT pxrefqueuekey FROM myschema.t2) OR 
    pxinsname IN (SELECT pxrefqueuekey FROM myschema.t3)
);
```

you can see if the indexes are working. You can also use this query without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to test whether my simplified query deletes the elements you want to delete.

Comment: Hi, The query you gave doesn't return the same results that my original query is giving.

Comment: However, you can try the indexes and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` as well. You should also try to elimate the outer subquery, to retrieve a better perormance.